# Probability that one of the cells of a random Venn Diagram exceeds a given threshold.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I apologize if this has been answered before; I found a couple similar questions on Math.SE, but none were exactly the same.

Suppose we are given a universe $\Omega$ and integers $b_1, b_2, S$ satisfying $0 < b_1, b_2 < S < |\Omega|$, and we choose two subsets $A,B \subset \Omega$ satisfying $|A|,|B| < S$ uniformly at random (with replacement).

What is the probability that at least one of the following conditions will be satisfied?

1. $|A \cap B| \geq b_1$
2. $|A^c \cap B| \geq b_2$
3. $|A \cap B^c| \geq b_2$
4. $|A^c \cap B^c| \geq b_1$

Edit: I would be interested in lower bounds if there's no exact solution!

Comment: Wanna verify my understanding: (1) "with replacement" means $A=B$ is allowed, right?  (I.e. it does _not_ mean $A,B$ are multisets allowing repeated elements of $\Omega$)  (2) Since the $4$ intersections together partition $\Omega$, the probability is $1$ when $2(B_1+B_2) \le |\Omega|$, right?

Comment: @antkam Correct on both counts!

Comment: If not for $S$, I feel this should have a simple solution.  But with $S$, there is no closed form that even counts how many $A$ has size $< S$, and I have no idea how to model the uniform drawing...  Very interesting question!  Where did this come from?

Comment: @antkam It comes from a problem in Ramsey theory: if you have two vertices in a graph, and set S,B_1,B_2 to certain Ramsey numbers, then if Omega is the rest of the vertices, A is the neighborhood for one vertex, and B is the neighborhood for the other vertex, the 4 conditions are necessary for the resulting graph to have no cliques or cocliques of a certain size.

Comment: @antkam In fact, the naive solution for 2(B_1 + B_2) \le |\Omega| is the basis of the proof of Ramsey's theorem (that Ram(k,k) \leq Ram(k,k-1) + Ram(k-1,k)). I'm interested in whether this bound can be improved by considering smaller B_i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I don't have time to investigate your problem and I don't know how far I'll be able to advance in it, so I provide the calculations below in a hope that it can be helpful to somebody to proceed further and finally to win the bounty.

Put $T=|\Omega|$. A total number of possible choices of a pair $(A,B)$ is $$N=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{S-1} {T\choose i}\right)^2.$$ Given a set $a=|A|$, a number of possibilities to choose a set $B$ *not* satisfying any of the conditions is

$$M(a)=\sum\left\{ {a\choose i} {{T-a}\choose j}:i,j\ge 0, a-b_2<i<b_1, T-b_1<j<b_2, i+j<S\right\}.$$

So the total number of possibilities to choose a set $B$ *not* satisfying any of conditions is

$$M=\sum_{a=0}^{S-1} {T\choose a} M(a).$$

With these formulae we can estimate the required probability $1-\tfrac MN$ for values of parameters in which we are interested by a computer. Since with fixed $n$ binomial coefficients ${n\choose k}$ grows very fast, I expect that $M$ is almost equal to its largest summand $${T\choose a}{a\choose i} {{T-a}\choose j}=\frac{T!}{i! j!(a-i)!(T-a-j)!},$$

that is

$$M\approx \max\left\{\tfrac{T!}{i!j!(a-i)!(T-a-j)!}: 0\le a<S, i, j\ge 0, a-b_2<i<b_1, T-b_1<j<b_2, i+j<S\right\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Hopefully the calculations will be useful in finding the eventual solution.